# Restrict Versions iOS - NO minimum version

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

**Detail: NO is the minimum version**

Is there any way I can restrict versions of iOS?

For example, I have developed an application and would like it swirled in iOS versions 7.x.x and iOS 8.1.x. In short, I would avoid the application was installed on the iOS versions 8.0.x.

How come? Currently in iOS 7 works perfectly on iOS 8.1.x also, but on iOS 8.0.x the application presents several problems, including constant crashes.

Comment: Apple will not likely allow you to submit a version that does not work on iOS 8. iOS 7 is no longer being signed or supported by Apple, so iOS 8 is the only thing that **they** care about, so they won't even bother looking at an app that doesn't work on it, and just reject it outright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible. Apple only accepts new apps in the App Store which are able to run on the current iOS(iOS 8+ at the moment). They don't care about earlier iOS versions.

Simply said: Apps have to run on the newest iOS version.

Also I'd recommend you to fix the iOS 8 errors instead, because even if you could do that. Over 50% of all iOS users are using iOS 8. That means that your app won't be seen by many users. If you have trouble to resolve your errors, I'm sure there are people, maybe on this website, which will help you.